# Doubt in this question involving logarithm

Tags: logarithms

If $\log2= 0.301$, then how many number of digits are in $2^{64}$?

What I did:
$$\log(2)^{64}=\log2^{64}=64\log2=64\log2=19.264$$

Number of digits comes out to be $5$. But answer is $20$? I have written $\log 2$ raise to the power $64$

Comment: $2^64\ne2^{64}$

Comment: The number of digits comes from a base ten logarithm, not base two.

Comment: How about a better title to your question?

Comment: Your edit, replacing $1.9$ by $19$, means you now have the right answer. Extra useful thing to remember: since $10^3 = 1000 \approx 1024 = 2^{10}$ the number of decimal digits is about $1/3$ the number of binary digits.

Comment: "Number of digits comes out to be $5$": what do you mean ?

Comment: How? Answer is 19.264. It means 5 digits. @EthanBolker

Comment: @mathematics: ouch, you completely missed the problem!

Comment: @YvesDaoust what do you mean? :(

Comment: That $19.264$ is the base $10$ logarithm of the number you're interested in. The base $10$ logarithm of a number is (approximately) the number of base $10$ digits it has. It's "approximate" because the number of digits is, of course, an integer. So you round the $19.264$ up to $20$.

Comment: You are asked the number of digits in $18446744073709551616$. The number of digits in $64\log 2$ is infinite as this is an irrational number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because number of digits it's$$[64\log2]+1=20,$$ which gives the answer.

In the general case if $n$ is a number of digits of natural $N$ then $n=[\log{N}]+1$

Indeed, let $N=a_0\cdot10^{n-1}+a_1\cdot10^{n-2}+...+a_{n-1}$, where $a_i\in\{0,1,...,9\}$ and $a_0\neq0$.

Hence, $n$ is a number of digits.

We see that $10^{n-1}\leq N<10^n$ or $n-1\leq\log{N}<n$,

which says $[\log{N}]=n-1$ and we are done!

Comment: I did not understand @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: @mathematics Number of digits of natural $N$ it's $[\log{N}]+1$. It's very known, but I am ready to prove it.

Comment: Please, can you prove it? @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: Thankyou @MichaelRozenberg. I got it.

Comment: @mathematics I posted it. Maybe it helps more.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let's call $n$ the number of digits of $2^{64}$ then

$$10^{n-1}\le2^{64}<10^n$$

so,

$$n-1\le\log 2^{64}<n$$ $$n-1\le 64\log 2<n$$

Can you finish?

Comment: No, I did not get it. @Arnaldo. From the very first step

Comment: @mathematics: for example, 21 has two digits so we can write $10^{2-1}\le 21< 10^2$. That is because $10^n$ is the first number with $n+1$ digits. Is it clear?

Answer (score 0):

See that $100 = 10^2$ and $1000 = 10^3$ and so on.  The number of digits in both those numbers is one more than the exponent on $10$.  If we write any 3-digit number as a power of 10, then the exponent will be between $2$ and $3$.  For instance,  $423 = 10^{2.6263\ldots},$  where, of course $2.6263\ldots$ is the base-10 log of $423.$

Using this principle we can do this:

$$2^{64}= \left(10^{\log 2}\right)^{64} = 10^{64\log } = 10^{19.26\ldots}. $$

So we know the number has 20 digits.